# mysqld.exe error while changing Template in xampp

Tags: php, mysql, database, templates, xampp

Hi I am new in using xampp as my localhost, I am using Avada theme in Wordpress. After changing the template in Page attribute section from Default Template to Portfolio Two Column, I suddenly got mysqld.exe error.

I hope anyone could help me with this. Best regards!

Comment: xampp does not have "themes"

Comment: sorry to confuse you, I mean I used xampp as my localhost, I am using wordpress theme.

Comment: ok.. so whats the error?

Comment: when trying to start mysql in xampp i get this error:

10:19:24 AM  [mysql]  Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:19:24 AM  [mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:19:24 AM  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:19:24 AM  [mysql]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:19:24 AM  [mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:19:24 AM  [mysql]  If you need more help, copy and post this
10:19:24 AM  [mysql]  entire log window on the forums

that occur after I changed the template style in wordpress

Comment: here's the complete log https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwivgWzW0jCfLTlkU1FjTE1VajQ

i dont have any idea how to check the error on that log for I am still a newbie.